# SSL connection with client-side certificate

Tags: python, encryption, twisted, ssl

Is it possible for a client to establish a SSL connection to a server using the server's certificate already exchanged through other means?

The point would be to encrypt the connection using the certificate already with the client and not have to rely on the server to provide it. The server would still have the private key for the certificate the client uses.

This question isn't language specific, but answers specific to python and twisted are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The certificates in SSL/TLS are only used for authentication, the encryption itself is done by shared keys negotiated during the handshake.

If you want to use certificates, you'll always need at least the SSL/TLS server to have a certificate (which may be the TCP client). You can indeed swap the role of the client and server when making the connection. That is, the SSL/TLS server doesn't have to be the TCP server, but can be the TCP client. See definition in the [specification glossary](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#appendix-B):

> ```
>   client
>       The application entity that initiates a TLS connection to a
>       server.  This may or may not imply that the client initiated the
>       underlying transport connection.  The primary operational
>       difference between the server and client is that the server is
>       generally authenticated, while the client is only optionally
>       authenticated.
> ```

However, doing so can lead to difficulties. Just like a server in a traditional SSL/TLS connection can't detect whether the request have been through a MITM (it's solely the client's responsibility to check the server certificate, without client-certificate authentication), making the TCP client be the SSL/TLS server makes it hard for the TCP client to know that it's talking to the TCP server it intended: the server could in fact be a MITM. You'd need to consider whether this suits your needs.

In Python, you should be able to choose the orientation of your SSL/TLS socket using the `server_side` parameter of [`ssl.wrap_socket`](http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket).

> The server would still have the private key for the certificate the
> client uses.

This doesn't make sense at all. Private keys should be kept private by the party to which the certificate was issued.

Perhaps you're after a Pre-Shared Key mechanism instead.

Comment: By 'key' I mean the CSR, which includes the public key. I want the client to get that public key with the application for instance, then use it to get the symmetric key from the server, which will then be used to encrypt further communications. The secure exchange of that public key not withstanding, if that assumption is made for the sake of argument, no further certificate from the server should be necessary.

Comment: Ah... well you did say 'private key' (feel free to edit your question if you meant public key). If you want the client to authenticate the server using the server's public key, do it the normal way: set up a cert+priv. key on the server and import its certificate as a trusted certificate into the client (you could bundle it with your application if it's a self-signed cert or your own CA cert).

Comment: I guess you're right it is a sort of Pre-Sahred Key mechanism, I just want the key to be asymmetric.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with PSK. What you seem to be after is the distribution of your own server cert to your client app so that the client app can identify the server when it connects to it, without depending on established CAs.

Comment: Following your edit, this is much simpler than what you had in mind initially: you should be able to pass that cert explicitly to `ca_certs=` on the client.

Answer (score 0):

In TLS, the server (the side which `listen`'s for connections) always needs a certificate. Client-side certificates may be used only for peer authentication, but not for the channel encryption.

Keep in mind also, that you can't simply "encrypt" a connection without some infrastructure to verify the certificates in some way (using certification authorities, or trust databases for example). Encryption without certificate validity verification does not hold against an active adversary (google for 'man in the middle attack' for more details on this).

Comment: I don't intend to start a discussion on the effectiveness of CAs, but I aim to circumvent them even if just to test it out.